# Lightning web component - how to get width of an element in javascript

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, template

I want to get the width of an element in js and based on that width want to perform some animations. I am resizing the width of the below div from 1112px to 752px through CSS animation, when it reaches 752px I want animation on another element to begin.

```
HTML
<div id="mapId" class="map-root" lwc:dom="manual"></div>

CSS
.map-root {
    height: 370px;
    width: 1112px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.map-root-animation {
    animation: mapWidthAnimation 0.5s forwards 0s ease;
}

@keyframes mapWidthAnimation {
    0% {
        width: 1112px;
        height: 370px;
    }

    100% {
        width: 752px;
        height: 370px;

    }
}
```

On the click event of a button:

```
this.template.querySelector('.map-root').classList.add('map-root-animation');
let mapWidth = this.template.querySelector('.map-root');
console.log(mapWidth.style.width);// I get blank value in the console.
if (mapWidth.style.width == 752px) { //do something }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The style attribute tells you what the style was set to. To get the actual current size, use getBoundingClientRect():

```
console.log(mapWidth.getBoundingClientRect().width);
```

Note that this will be an actual number, not a string. For example, it'll be equal to `752`, not `752px`).

However, what you're probably looking for is to watch for the [end of the animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/animationend_event):

```
mapWidth.addEventListener('animationend', this.handleAnimationEnd.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks again @sfdcfox

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox ! getBoundingClientRect() is indeed the ticket. Thing is the querySelector result is quite inscrutable in debug because of the Proxy() that the `aura_prod.js` hides it behind. Is there some reference page which documents the members/methods that we can expect to "reach" through the Proxy which Aura imposes over the HTML elements?

Comment: @BorisGaspic You can check the [Locker API Viewer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer) for methods and attributes you'll have access to.

Comment: @sfdcfox great reference, thank you for the link! I wasn't aware of that page