# Is there a similar property to flexipageRegionWidth in Community?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, experience-cloud, responsive-design

I have a LWC where i use flexipageRegionWidth property but i have to use this component in a community and it doesn't work.
Is there a solution for knowing the size of a region in Experience Cloud ?
I didn't find anything about this.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You can find the window width or height via the `window` reference and can listen for changes in the window size too:

```
    connectedCallback() {
        this.applySize();
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.applySize);
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.applySize);
    }

    applySize = () => {
        const w = window.innerWidth;
        const h = window.innerHeight;
        // Use these sizes in whatever logic you need them for here
    };
```

LWC wraps the DOM `window` for security and exposes about half of the functionality. You can see what is supported here in the [Window vs SecureWindow Compatibility](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer) list.

Comment: Yes but if i drop the component in a small region ? Like a side bar, i can't use window :/

Comment: Hi @OphélieA, Good point. Inside an LWC you should be able to get your own bounding rectangle - see e.g. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302092/lightning-web-component-how-to-get-width-of-an-element-in-javascript.

Comment: Thank you very much, it really helped me !